# OpenCv C++ to datatype OpenCv4Android analogies

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to convert an OpenCv C++ code to OpenCv4Android using the latest OpenCv4Android-2.4.4 API.
I am very much confused for datatype analogies from C++ to Java.
Please help me clear of my confusion for the same.

Some of the confusing analogies -

C++ - Java

Point2f - Point
Point3f- Point

In java what is ?

MatOfPoint2f, MatOfPoint3f, MatOfByte, MatOfFloat... etc ? What are there C++ synonyms.

This would be a great help for me, as i am trying to port my C++ working code to java. And currently i am not able to figure out, what datatype to use for few of the C++ directives.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See the OpenCV core package documentation for a list of types: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/package-summary.html

Comment: I asked the same question on official OpenCv Forum. And it was been answered in following manner. Please refer the link - [ Confusion between OpenCv4Android and C++ data types](http://answers.opencv.org/question/11021/confusion-between-opencv4android-and-c-data-types/)